# Invalid resource path specified

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, apk

I have copied the app-debug.apk from outputs of android studio project and trying to run the apk file on the phone but getting this error :

```
Invalid resource path specifed
```

This is my project structure :

[image]

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? Do you know the class and method triggering the issue? Without any additional info, it will be hard to get any help.

Comment: the error is coming on installing the apk file. where I can get the traces from ?

Comment: Run `adb logcat` in a separate shell window.

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause of this error is the method you sent the file to your device.

I sent the apk file using whatsapp messenger and this error was shown.

But when I sent the file using Bluetooth the apk was installed successfully.